# How to sort 4 integers using only min() and max()? Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to sort 4 integers input by the user into numerical order using only the min() and max() functions in python. I can get the highest and lowest number easily, but cannot work out a combination to order the two middle numbers? Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm guessing your input is something like this?

```
string = input('Type your numbers, separated by a space')
```

Then I'd do:

```
numbers = [int(i) for i in string.strip().split(' ')]
amount_of_numbers = len(numbers)
sorted = []
for i in range(amount_of_numbers):
    x = max(numbers)
    numbers.remove(x)
    sorted.append(x)
print(sorted)
```

This will sort them using max, but min can also be used.

**If you *didn't have to* use min and max**:

```
string = input('Type your numbers, separated by a space')
numbers = [int(i) for i in string.strip().split(' ')]
numbers.sort()     #an optional reverse argument possible
print(numbers)
```

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could cut the number of rounds in half by using both max and min in each round.

Comment: We have literally only just started learning about python so I dont really even understand your  code.. This is what I came up with and it works: min_integer = min(first_integer, second_integer, third_integer, fourth_integer)
mid_low_integer = min(max(first_integer, second_integer), max(third_integer, fourth_integer))
mid_high_integer = max(min(first_integer, second_integer), min(third_integer, fourth_integer))
max_integer = max(first_integer, second_integer, third_integer, fourth_integer)

Comment: That is a terrible way to learn. Give your professor a time out

Answer (score 0):

LITERALLY just min and max?  Odd, but, why not.  I'm about to crash, but I think the following would work:

```
# Easy
arr[0] = max(a,b,c,d)

# Take the smallest element from each pair. 
#
# You will never take the largest element from the set, but since one of the
# pairs will be (largest, second_largest) you will at some point take the
# second largest.   Take the maximum value of the selected items - which
# will be the maximum of the items ignoring the largest value.
arr[1] = max(min(a,b)
    min(a,c)
    min(a,d)
    min(b,c)
    min(b,d)
    min(c,d))

# Similar logic, but reversed, to take the smallest of the largest of each
# pair - again omitting the smallest number, then taking the smallest.
arr[2] = min(max(a,b)
    max(a,c)
    max(a,d)
    max(b,c)
    max(b,d)
    max(c,d))

# Easy
arr[3] = min(a,b,c,d)
```

Answer (score 0):

For Tankerbuzz's result for the following:

```
first_integer = 9
second_integer = 19
third_integer = 1
fourth_integer = 15
```

I get 1, 15, 9, 19 as the ascending values.

The following is one of the forms that gives symbolic form of the ascending values (using i1-i4 instead of first_integer, etc...):

```
Min(i1, i2, i3, i4)
Max(Min(i4, Max(Min(i1, i2), Min(i3, Max(i1, i2))), Max(i1, i2, i3)), Min(i1, i2, i3, Max(i1, i2)))
Max(Min(i1, i2), Min(i3, Max(i1, i2)), Min(i4, Max(i1, i2, i3)))
Max(i1, i2, i3, i4)
```

It was generated by a 'bubble sort' using the Min and Max functions of SymPy (a python CAS):

```
def minmaxsort(v):
    """return a sorted list of the elements in v using the
    Min and Max functions.

    Examples
    ========

    >>> minmaxsort(3, 2, 1)
    [1, 2, 3]
    >>> minmaxsort(1, x, y)
    [Min(1, x, y), Max(Min(1, x), Min(y, Max(1, x))), Max(1, x, y)]
    >>> minmaxsort(1, y, x)
    [Min(1, x, y), Max(Min(1, y), Min(x, Max(1, y))), Max(1, x, y)]
    """
    from sympy import Min, Max
    v = list(v)
    v0 = Min(*v)
    for j in range(len(v)):
        for i in range(len(v) - j - 1):
            w = v[i:i + 2]
            v[i:i + 2] = [Min(*w), Max(*w)]
    v[0] = v0
    return v
```

Answer (score -1):

I have worked it out.

```
min_integer = min(first_integer, second_integer, third_integer, fourth_integer)
mid_low_integer = min(max(first_integer, second_integer), max(third_integer, fourth_integer))
mid_high_integer = max(min(first_integer, second_integer), min(third_integer, fourth_integer))
max_integer = max(first_integer, second_integer, third_integer, fourth_integer)
```